# How can i achieve the below design in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

[image: Expected Curve Shaped View]

I'm little bit stuck here to achieve below design in one of my app.

IMAGE

My code is here,

```
<View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: colors.green, width: '100%', height: '40%', borderBottomLeftRadius: 100, borderBottomRightRadius: 100}}>
        </View>
</View>
```

Is it possible to get this done by using react native svg?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: checkout this snack https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/thrilled-tea

Comment: Can you please tell me how to achieve this with different shapes. I mean the procedure.